# Keep a private file on github without gitignore

Tags: github, gitignore

Several of my Github repos have files I don't want to publicize. Initially, my solution to this was to use ".gitignore". Recently though, I accidentally deleted an entire repo. I could recover the files on GitHub, but I couldn't recover the "ignored" files. Is there I way I can store all my files on GitHub but choose to make some files private?

Comment: Make a private repository. Github may be the wrong tool if you're looking to back up your files.

Comment: @Robert I am also looking to show my work.

Comment: You could encrypt the files so that anybody can see but not read them. But I still think you're using the wrong tool.